# Conditional expectation of two dependent rvs which consist of independent uniformly distributed rvs

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

I am self-thaught in advanced probability and one of the exercises which I found is:

"Let $\xi$ and $\eta$ be independent rvs uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$. Let $X=\xi\eta$ and $Y=\xi/\eta$. Calculate $E(X|Y)$"

So, the general formula is $\int_{x \in range(X)} xf_X(x|Y=y)dx$.
We can find $f_X(x|Y=y)$ using $\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$

I don't know how to compute pdf's $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ and $f_Y(y)$.

And in our case we have $x=\xi\eta$, so how we can write $dx$ then.

Can anybody help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inverting $X=\Xi H$ and $Y=\Xi/H$ yields $\Xi=\sqrt{XY}$ and $H=\sqrt{X/Y}$, so

\begin{eqnarray*}
f_{X,Y}(x,y)
&=&
f_{\Xi,H}(\xi(x,y),\eta(x,y))\frac{\partial(\xi,\eta)}{\partial(x,y)}
\\
&=&
I_{[0,1]^2}\left(\sqrt{xy},\sqrt{x/y}\right)\left|\begin{array}{cc}\frac12\sqrt{\frac yx}&\frac12\sqrt{\frac1{xy}}\\\frac12\sqrt{\frac xy}&-\frac12\sqrt{\frac x{y^3}}\end{array}\right|
\\
&=&
I_{[0,1]}(x)I_{[x,1/x]}(y)\cdot\frac1{2y}\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

Then

$$
f_Y(y)=\int_0^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm dx=\begin{cases}\frac12&y\le1\;,\\\frac1{2y^2}&y\gt1\;,\end{cases}
$$

and thus

\begin{eqnarray*}
f_X(x\mid Y=y)
&=&\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}
\\
&=&
I_{[0,1]}(x)I_{[x,1/x]}(y)\cdot\begin{cases}\frac1y&y\le1\\y&y\gt1\end{cases}
\\
&=&
I_{[0,1]}(x)\left(I_{[x,1]}(y)\cdot\frac1y+I_{[1,1/x]}(y)\,y\right)
\\
&=&I_{[0,1]}(y)I_{[0,y]}(x)\cdot\frac1y+I_{[1,\infty]}(y)I_{[0,1/y]}(x)\,y
\\
&=&I_{[0,1]}(y)\mathsf{Uniform}_{[0,y]}(x)+I_{[1,\infty]}(y)\mathsf{Uniform}_{[0,1/y]}(x)\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

That is, $X$ is uniformly distributed conditional on $Y$, on $[0,y]$ if $y\le1$ and on $[0,1/y]$ if $y\gt1$.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! It is very helpful.